# Displaying string with html tags in wpf

Tags: html, .net, wpf, xaml

I need to display data with html tags in WPF app.

For example I have string with following format:

```
<html><body><b>HI!</b></body></html>
```

Result:

**HI!**

How can I display it in any control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. To people with similar question: just use webbrowser helper as in this link:
http://thomasfreudenberg.com/archive/2010/08/01/binding-webbrowser-content-in-wpf/